# android webview doesn't show left side

Tags: android, webview

I want to show a forum on my app using webview, it worked fine except that the left side of the website is hidden, how I can fix it.

for example, I want the website to be like this:

[image]

but it appears like this:

[image]

here is my code:

```
  <LinearLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

 <WebView
     android:id="@+id/webView1"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>


  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: how did you fixed it?

Answer (score 1):

Webview structure is looking fine, please cross check html page.

Comment: ً@user4346594 so the problem must be fixed from the website and not the app, right ?

Answer (score 0):

Your layout structure looks good. I think the problem is that your css webview is wrong or something is broken. To be sure you can remove the loading on the webview and set a background color to see the space taken by the webview.

Answer (score 0):

Check your HTML url or HTML file in device's chrome browser. If its not looking fine there then its HTML contents issues otherwise webview's.